# Subtract 8 hours from time

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have google table with time columns. These columns are `Time format`, and i use formula to calculate worked hours - 8 hours needed to know whether i worked over 8 hours or less.

Pretty simple formula.

```
=E*-TIME(8;0;0)
```

But when i work less than 8 hours, it shows `23` hours instead of `-7` hours for example. I want my top **F1** cell to count sum of all over/less worked hours, and the rest **F** contain **E*-TIME(8;0;0)** values.

Comment: @player0
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s3yqTaTZUlBDa6uXBkha3gTt8ds32ubV-GNykZGLUoY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Time - Time = Duration, so try to format your result cell to be duration

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IF(A2<"8:00"; TEXT("8:00"-A2; "-hh:mm"); A2-"8:00")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:E="";;
 IF(E3:E<TIMEVALUE("8:00"); TEXT("8:00"-E3:E; "-h:mm:ss"); E3:E-"8:00")))
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZvnS5f_PXQtrYh7HesxXSThXGruolX2jEPspg1F7IME/edit#gid=0)

Comment: working! Could you please also help me, how to add hours so it will show 24+ hours, because after its more than 24, it counts from the beginning from 0 to 24 again.

Answer (score 0):

Because substraction and addition time are durations, you can format durations with text formula with [HH] as hour duration

```
=text(time(2,4,4)-time(5,4,4),"[HH]:mm")
```

But you can actually format your Cell to duration.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.